# Making a for loop that edits a list in a data structure

Tags: c, data-structures

The code that I'm trying to write is supposed to take given data by the user and put it into a data structure, which works perfectly. What is going wrong is when I try to remove a entry( if(choice == 2). All it has to do is take that entry and make it empty but I didn't like the idea of empty space. The for loop that I tried to make was to take the top entry and move everything down one but what it does is take the first entry and copy it to the second, leaving the others alone. Any help on how to take the data and just delete the entry to move them down one would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct  book  {     //This is the data structure
    char personName[15];
    char personLname[15];
    char phoneNumber[15];
    char null[4];
} Book;

static int loopValue;// this is going to loop the program forever until the 
    //loop is broke
main()
{

    int index = 0;
    int choice;
    Book *ptrBook = (Book*)malloc(sizeof(Book));
    int i,j;
    int stopValue = 1;

    while(stopValue=0)
    {
        printf("\t\tPhone Book Application\n");
        printf("\t1. Add Contact\t\t2. Remove Contact\n");
        printf("\t3. Show Contacts\t10. Exit\n");
        printf("\tChoice: ");
        scanf("%i",&choice);
        printf("\n\n");

        if(choice == 1)     // this is the add person, it takes the print if 
                /and puts it into the data structure
    {
        ptrBook = (Book*)realloc(ptrBook, sizeof(Book)*(index + 1));
        printf("What is the FIRST name: ");
        scanf("%s",ptrBook[index].personName);
        printf("What is the LAST name: ");
        scanf("%s",ptrBook[index].personLname);
        printf("What is the number: ");
        scanf("%s",ptrBook[index].phoneNumber);
        printf("\nAdded to the Phone Book.\n");
        printf("\nName: %s %s\n",ptrBook[index].personName, 
ptrBook[index].personLname);
        printf("Phone Number: %s",ptrBook[index].phoneNumber);
        index++;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)       // this removes people from the data 
                         //structure
    {
        loopValue == 0;
        printf("Who would you like to remove?\n\n");
        for(i=0;i<index;i++)        // this loops prints out the names to 
                               //choose from
        {

     printf("%i. %s %s\n",i+1,ptrBook[i].personName,ptrBook[i].personLname);
        }
        printf("Who would you like to remove? ");
        scanf("%i",choice);
        for(i=choice;i<0;i--)  //THIS IS WHAT NEED HELP WITH PLZ
        {                       //
            strcpy(ptrBook[i-2].personName,ptrBook[i-1].personName);    //
            strcpy(ptrBook[i-2].personLname,ptrBook[i-1].personLname);  //
            strcpy(ptrBook[i-2].phoneNumber,ptrBook[i-1].phoneNumber);  //
        }                   `//
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%i",&choice);
    }
    if(choice == 3)     // this loops to print out all the values in the 
                  //data structure
    {
        for(i=0;i<index;i++)
        {
            printf("%s %s\n",ptrBook[i].personName,ptrBook[i].personLname);
            printf("%i. %s\n\n\n",index,ptrBook[i].phoneNumber);
        }
    }
    else if(choice == 4)
    {
        //make code to sort names
    }
    else if(choice == 5)
    {
        //find a phone number for a given name
    }
    else if(choice == 6)
    {
        //random person for you to call
    }
    else if(choice== 7)
    {
        //delete everyone
    }
    else if(choice == 8)        // this exits the program by changing the 
                      //loop variable to something that makes the loop false
    {
        printf("Exiting");
        stopValue = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ok concentrate. You have an array books, ie. `{ book1, book2, book3, book4, book5 }`. You want to remove book3. So you need to move all books after book3 one to the left <- `for` each book after book3 starting from book4 copy it one to the left. There is no need for `strcpy`, you can just copy the whole struct `ptrBook[3] = ptrBook[4];`. After moving, remember to call `realloc` and decrement `index`.

Comment: Something went wrong when you copied in the code, there's two stray #include before the code begins properly.

Comment: You missed `<stdlib.h>` but use functions (such as `malloc()`) that are declared in it.  Add the missing header.  Don't compile code where function declarations are missing.  Also, plain `main()` (no return type) is only valid in C for C90/C89 or pre-standard C; since C99, it has been invalid — you should use `int main(void)` or (at a pinch) `int main()`, though that is definitely inferior.  You should not be writing C90 code any more; it has been out of date for most of two decades.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry if I don't understand the first time through, still learning C in my intro programming class. I changed it so it would be less complicated while testing. I made it so it is just an if statement so that it I want remove the item 1 it does ptrBook[0]=ptrBook[1]; and it still replaces the second entry with the first entry. ie, it prints out "Who would you like to remove: 1. John Doe 2. Jane Doe." when I push 1 what it does is "1.John Doe 2. John Doe"

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a LOT of issues. In the future, please make sure to clean up your code really thoroughly before posting a question. I've taken the time to clean up a lot of it because I hate myself, so I hope you appreciate. First, a bug list:

1 and 2) Your condition in the while loop is actually an assignment: please turn on warnings on your compiler, because they will catch stuff like this. It's also erroneous with your initalization of `stopValue`.

3) The `loopValue` is used inconsistently throughout the code, and is not the thing that controls your while loop.

4) Inside `if (choice == 2)`, `loopValue == 0` means compare it to 0, not set it to 0. That has no effect on your program, but you've made the =, == error twice now. That's really basic stuff that you absolutely have to get a grip on.

5) In the same if section, your scanf where you set `choice` didn't have & in front of choice, meaning the variable wouldn't actually be set to the value typed in.

6) Same section, the last printf and scanf are probably not meant to be there? In any case they bring the input to an unintuitive halt, which would render the program useless to anyone who didn't have the source code.

7) The `if (choice == 3)` wasn't an else if.

8) The quit option is 8 in the source code, but the menu says it's 10.

After all that, here's the code (with a lot of stuff that didn't have anything to do with the problem you were having taken out)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct book {     //This is the data structure
    char personName[15];
    char personLname[15];
    char phoneNumber[15];
    char null[4];
} Book;

static int loopValue;
int main(void) {
    int index = 0;
    int choice;
    Book *ptrBook = (Book*) malloc(sizeof(Book));
    int i, j;
    int stopValue = 0; // was 1

    while (stopValue == 0) { // was =
        printf("\t\tPhone Book Application\n");
        printf("\t1. Add Contact\t\t2. Remove Contact\n");
        printf("\t3. Show Contacts\t8. Exit\n");
        printf("\tChoice: ");
        scanf("%i", &choice);
        printf("\n\n");

        if (choice == 1) {
            ptrBook = (Book*) realloc(ptrBook, sizeof(Book)*(index + 1));
            printf("What is the FIRST name: ");
            scanf("%s",ptrBook[index].personName);
            printf("What is the LAST name: ");
            scanf("%s",ptrBook[index].personLname);
            printf("What is the number: ");
            scanf("%s",ptrBook[index].phoneNumber);
            printf("\nAdded to the Phone Book.\n");
            printf("\nName: %s %s\n",ptrBook[index].personName,
            ptrBook[index].personLname);
            printf("Phone Number: %s",ptrBook[index].phoneNumber);
            index++;
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            loopValue = 0; // was ==
            printf("Who would you like to remove?\n\n");
            for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                printf("%i. %s %s\n", i+1, ptrBook[i].personName, ptrBook[i].personLname);
            }
            printf("Who would you like to remove? ");
            scanf("%d", &choice); // didn't have &
            for (int i = (choice - 1); i < (index - 1); i++) {
                ptrBook[i] = ptrBook[i + 1];
            }
            index--;
            // used to be redundant/confusing/wrong printf and scanf
        } else if (choice == 3) { // used to not be else if
            for (i = 0; i<index; i++) {
                printf("%s %s\n", ptrBook[i].personName, ptrBook[i].personLname);
                printf("%i. %s\n\n\n", index, ptrBook[i].phoneNumber);
            }
        } else if (choice == 8) { // Should've been 10
            printf("Exiting");
            stopValue = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen what happens when you reach `printf("%i. %s\n\n\n", index, ptrBook[i].phoneNumber);`?  (hint: `index` shouldn't be there, it should be `i + 1`) What if the user enters `100000` at `printf("Who would you like to remove? ");`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No I have not, but I knew there would be other problems that I simply have no interest in fixing. Solving the problem that the actual question was about took precedence, and then the rest was just stuff I discovered along the way.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many little problems with your code that it is hard to know where to begin. Probably the most glaring is the failure to validate the the return of `scanf` and your failure to empty `stdin` of any extraneous characters after each input leaving your program just waiting to enter an endless-loop on the first errant keystroke. You cannot use the `"%s"` conversion specifier to read names (many are two-part names) and you will stop reading at the first whitespace and the remainder of the name will be taken as the next input. The same applies to reading a phone number (which would trigger an endless loop if a whitespace and punctuation is included).

Which brings up a larger recommendation of using `fgets` instead of `scanf` for all line-oriented input (such as taking user input). You can use `sscanf` to parse integer values from the input and you avoid a whole host of pitfalls inherent in new C programmers taking input with `scanf`. Don't skimp on buffer size. For example `#define MAXC 1024` and then `char buf[MAXC];` would be adequate for most user input.

Next, when doing a menu, consider using `switch () { case 1: ...; break; case 2: ...; break }` instead of the long chain of `if (...) {...} else if (...) {...}, etc...`. It provides more readable code;

There are many, many more corrections made to your code which are explained in the comments inline below, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NULLSZ    4     /* if you need a constant #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNMNUM 15

typedef struct book {
    char personName[MAXNMNUM];  /* use constants for array sizes */
    char personLname[MAXNMNUM];
    char phoneNumber[MAXNMNUM];
    char null[NULLSZ];  /* no clue what this is for */
} Book;

/* helper function to empty extraneous characters from stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) /* See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1 */
{
    int index = 0;
    Book *ptrBook = malloc (sizeof *ptrBook);  /* do NOT cast malloc return */

    for (;;) {      /* loop continually */
        int rtn,    /* return for scanf */
            choice = 0;
        /* you only need a single fputs - not muliple printf calls
         * there is no conversion taking place, so printf not neeeded.
         */
        fputs ( "\nPhone Book Application\n\n"
                " 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact\n"
                " 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit\n"
                "\nChoice: ", stdout);
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &choice);    /* ALWAYS VALIDATE EVERY INPUT */
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* check if user canceled input with Ctrl+d */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn < 1) { /* check for matching or input failure */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();  /* always empty stdin before next input */
            continue;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* ditto */

        if (choice == 1) {  /* add book */
            char *p;
            /* don't realloc every addition - very inefficient.
             * don't realloc the pointer itself, use a temp pointer
             * or you create memory leak on failure.
             */
            void *tmp = realloc (ptrBook, sizeof *ptrBook * (index + 1));
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc-ptrBook");
                break;
            }
            ptrBook = tmp;  /* assign new block to ptrBook */

            fputs ("What is the FIRST name: ", stdout);
            /* don't read line-oriented input with scanf, use fgets
             * if (scanf ("%s", ptrBook[index].personName) != 1) {
             */
            if (!fgets (ptrBook[index].personName, MAXNMNUM, stdin)) {
                fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
                break;
            }
            p = ptrBook[index].personName;  /* set convenience pointer */
            p[strcspn (p, "\r\n")] = 0;     /* trim '\n' from end of str */

            fputs ("What is the LAST name: ", stdout);
            if (!fgets (ptrBook[index].personLname, MAXNMNUM, stdin)) {
                fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
                break;
            }
            p = ptrBook[index].personLname; /* set convenience pointer */
            p[strcspn (p, "\r\n")] = 0;     /* trim '\n' from end of str */

            fputs ("What is the number: ", stdout);
            if (!fgets (ptrBook[index].phoneNumber, MAXNMNUM, stdin)) {
                fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
                break;
            }
            p = ptrBook[index].phoneNumber; /* set convenience pointer */
            p[strcspn (p, "\r\n")] = 0;     /* trim '\n' from end of str */

            printf ("\nAdded to the Phone Book.\n"
                    "\nName: %s %s\nPhone Number: %s\n", 
                    ptrBook[index].personName,
                    ptrBook[index].personLname, 
                    ptrBook[index].phoneNumber);

            index++;    /* increment index */
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {     /* remove entry */
            putchar ('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                printf (" %d. %s %s\n", i + 1, ptrBook[i].personName,
                        ptrBook[i].personLname);
            }

            fputs ("\nWho would you like to remove? ", stdout);
            rtn = scanf ("%d", &choice);
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
                break;
            }
            else if (rtn < 1) {
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                empty_stdin();
                continue;
            }
            else if (choice - 1 < 0 || index - 1 < choice - 1) {
                fputs ("error: out of range of valid indexes.\n", stderr);
                empty_stdin();
                continue;
            }
            /* remvove entry with memmove copying over removed entry */
            memmove (ptrBook + choice - 1, ptrBook + choice,
                    (index - choice) * sizeof *ptrBook);
            index -= 1; /* decrement index */
            /* realloc to remove entry */
            void *tmp = realloc (ptrBook, index * sizeof *ptrBook);
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc-index");
                break;
            }
            ptrBook = tmp;
        }
        if (choice == 3) {  /* output the entries */
            putchar ('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                printf ("%s %s\n%d. %s\n\n", ptrBook[i].personName,
                        ptrBook[i].personLname, i + 1, 
                        ptrBook[i].phoneNumber);
            }
        } else if (choice == 4) {
            //make code to sort names
        } else if (choice == 5) {
            //find a phone number for a given name
        } else if (choice == 6) {
            //random person for you to call
        } else if (choice == 7) {
            //delete everyone
        } else if (choice == 8) {
            printf ("Exiting\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** the use of `p` as a temporary pointer is simply for convenience and readability rather than having to type, e.g.  the full `ptrBook[index].personLname` over and over and causing the `strcspn` command to span multiple lines)

Also, consider removing `null` from your struct (no clue what that is for) and consider adding `index` or `nentries` as a member so the number of entries is always part of the struct itself (which makes things much more convenient when passing or returning the struct (or pointer to it) to/from other functions)

Below note how the program can now recover from invalid input. Try the same input with your code at the menu, e.g. `"I don't know"` and see what happens...

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/book_remove

Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: I don't know
error: invalid integer input.

Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 1
What is the FIRST name: Mark
What is the LAST name: Twain
What is the number: (444) 555-1212

Added to the Phone Book.

Name: Mark Twain
Phone Number: (444) 555-1212

Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 1
What is the FIRST name: Samuel
What is the LAST name: Clements
What is the number: (444) 555-1213

Added to the Phone Book.

Name: Samuel Clements
Phone Number: (444) 555-1213

Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 1
What is the FIRST name: Won Hung
What is the LAST name: Lo
What is the number: (444) 555-1214

Added to the Phone Book.

Name: Won Hung Lo
Phone Number: (444) 555-1214

Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 1
What is the FIRST name: Fred
What is the LAST name: Flintstone
What is the number: (444) 555-1215

Added to the Phone Book.

Name: Fred Flintstone
Phone Number: (444) 555-1215

Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 3

Mark Twain
1. (444) 555-1212

Samuel Clements
2. (444) 555-1213

Won Hung Lo
3. (444) 555-1214

Fred Flintstone
4. (444) 555-1215


Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 2

 1. Mark Twain
 2. Samuel Clements
 3. Won Hung Lo
 4. Fred Flintstone

Who would you like to remove? 2

Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 3

Mark Twain
1. (444) 555-1212

Won Hung Lo
2. (444) 555-1214

Fred Flintstone
3. (444) 555-1215


Phone Book Application

 1. Add Contact       2. Remove Contact
 3. Show Contacts ... 8. Exit

Choice: 8
Exiting
```

Look things over and make sure you understand what and why the changes were made. If not, then just ask for further clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example, I just started with learning C about six weeks ago. We have to turn on a program every week so it's really learn on the way kind of class. I appreciate your examples.

Comment: You are welcome. There is a lot to learn with C, so slow down and enjoy the education -- it's not a race. As you learn, just pick up good habits and add them to your C-toolbox. It may take an extra 5-lines to properly validate, but it will save you untold hours of debugging. When looping taking input, you must always account for *"What can be left in the input stream? (e.g. `stdin`)"* This is particularly true when using `scanf` where what will be left depends on the conversion specifier being used. (and whether leading whitespace is consumed). Good luck with your coding.

Comment: @DavidCRankin sorry for following up the next day, but I have gotten all the code worked out using your example and have a question about "tmp" in the realloc statement. What exactly is it? I didn't find tmp declared as a variable and couldn't find an example on the internet.

Comment: @stevejohn You *Never* `realloc` the pointer itself. (e.g. `myptr = realloc (myptr, newsize);` - BAD) Why? When (not if) `realloc` fails it returns `NULL`. If you assign that to `myptr` you have just overwritten the memory address for your original allocated block causing a *memory-leak* because that block can never be freed (you lost the pointer). So *Always* `realloc` with a temporary pointer to avoid this, e.g. `(void *tmp = realloc (myptr, newsize); if (!tmp) { /* handle error */ } else { myptr = tmp; maxsize = newsize; }`  Good question - add that to your C-toolbox.

Comment: It comes straight from [man 3 realloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). While *man pages* may seem cryptic at first, they contain precisely the information you need to use each function, the proper prototype (from which you can also obtain the order the parameters are passed in assembly) and most importantly the `"RETURN VALUE"` section describes exactly what occurs on function return (for both success and failure). You just have to make friends with the *man pages* -- they are are top-drawer item in your C-toolbox. On Linux, you just type `man funcname` and you have it.